# com.google.api.gax.rpc.DeadlineExceededException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED while using spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-secret-manager, spring-starter

Receiving this error while using secrets from GCP secret manager. It works fine when the service is deployed in cloud. But running on local machine throws DEADLINE_EXCEEDED.

Dependencies I am using

```
spring boot version = 2.3.6.RELEASE
<spring-cloud-gcp.version>1.2.8.RELEASE</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
<spring-boot-release.version>2.3.4.RELEASE</spring-boot-release.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

using secrets like this in application.yaml
Id: ${sm://projects/{project-id}/secrets/clientid}

already tried with different version of dependencies but no luck

Comment: Same problem here. It was working fine until recently, and I don't know why. Dis you find any solution ?